# use of undeclared variable in cpp file android

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I am calling this method from my main Activity

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_systems_kestrel_aerovision_datapackets_PacketBuilder_uBloxOnline(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz,
                                                                      jdouble lat, jdouble lng,
                                                                      jdouble altitude) {
    //        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // isDownloadingAssist = true;
   MGA_API_RESULT result = mgaInit();
```

then `MGA_API_RESULT` and `mgaInit()` method is defined in another `libmga.cpp` file

```
MGA_API_RESULT mgaInit(void)
{

    assert(s_sessionState == MGA_IDLE);
#ifdef WIN32
    InitializeCriticalSection(&s_mgaLock);
#else // WIN32
    pthread_mutex_init(&s_mgaLock, NULL);
#endif // WIN32
    MGA_API_OK;

    return MGA_API_OK;
}
```

header files I have already included. Now it is giving me this error of undefined variable when I execute this line:

```
MGA_API_RESULT result = mgaInit();
```

Comment: While C++ breaks some norms, in a general sense header files do not define (as in provide) function implementations.  Object files fed to your link step, or .so's loaded at runtime are what do that.

Comment: can you pelase explain what exactly i have to do so that it can help ..